# set a height on a item

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I have this javascript:

```
   $('.focus .box.border').height($('.box.border').maxHeight() + 'px');
```

I put a height on the `box.border` element. But how can i put a extra 15 pixels to the height. But how can I give an extra height to 15 pixels.

Thanks for helping

Comment: AFAIK, there is no jQuery `maxHeight` function... where does it come from? To add 15 pixel to the height, you have to use the addition operator `+`: `x + y`.

Comment: @FelixKling : http://css.dzone.com/articles/jquery-plugins-jstestdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.focus .box.border').height((parseInt($('.box.border').maxHeight())+15) + 'px');
```

Comment: No problem. Please access anwer as soon as you can.